# Map between Simplical and Singular Chain Groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have a question about the map above the red tagged line in the image below (source:P. Nadathur's script "Introduction to Homology"):

[image]

Here we have the simplicial chain group $L_n(X)$ freelly generated by n-simplices of X (I suppose that $X$ implicitely triangulated) and singular chain group $C_n(X)$ free generated by singular n-simplices $\sigma: \Delta_n \to X$ (here $\Delta_n$ are the standard n-simplices).

My questions: 
How does this map realised concretely?

And secondly: If $X= |K|$ where $K$ triangulation of $X$ and $|K|$ the underlying top. space. Can I identify $L_n(|K|)$ with $C_n(|K|)$

Comment: Just a nitpick: "f.g." usually means "finitely generated" rather than "freely generated" – $C^n(X)$ is definitely not finitely generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the first part of your question (if it is what is this map doing, I would answer that it remarks that a simplicial simplex is in particular a singular one), but for the second part it is no in general. For example, the group $L_1(S^1)$ with triangulation of $S^1$ consisting of a point $e$ and a segment $v$ is simply $\mathbb{Z}e\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, while $C_1(S^1)$ is the group of formal finite sums of points of $S^1$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. However, once you pass to homology, there will be an identification : $H^\Delta_n(X)\simeq H_n(X)$ for all space $X$ which admits a simplicial decomposition, the map inducing this isomorphism being precisely $i:L_n(X)\to C_n(X)$.

Comment: Concerning that simplicial simplex in a singular one: Do you mean this in the sense that such n-simplex $s \subset X $ can be considered as the map from $\Delta_n$ into it as subspace of $X$?

Comment: Yes, this is the translation that this map is doing.

Comment: Ah ok, that seemed to me to be a bit confusing to interpret here the n-simplex $s$ on the one hand as a map from $\Delta_n$ and on the other hand as the canonical image of $\Delta_n$ so as topological subset of $X$... or is one of this interpretations wrong?

Comment: You can indeed do these identifications : since a simplicial structure on $X$ is a collection of maps $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$ such that "the images $\sigma(\Delta)$ partition $X$" (well, not precisely but you get it), you can identify a map with its image (note that this is not possible for singular maps : for example, the maps $\sigma_1:\Delta^1=[0,1]\to X=[0,1]$ defined as $\sigma_1(x)=x$ and $\sigma_2:\Delta^1\to X$ defined as $\sigma_2(x)=x^2$ have the same images, but are not the same singular simplices).